# Metro App OnSearchActivated ProgressRing not displaying

Tags: windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, c#-5.0, winrt-async

I am implementing searching within my **Metro** application. The search works well, results and **UI** come up as expected with one problem though.

I try to display a `ProgressRing` before the search and hide it after the search completes, but it never gets displayed.

What am I missing, code snippet below:

```
    protected override void OnSearchActivated(Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.SearchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Some Metro designer generated code here

        // Show progress ring
        MainPage.Current.ResetProgressRingState(true);

        // Bind search results
        MainPage.Current.BindSearchResults(args.QueryText);

        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();

        // Hide progress ring
        MainPage.Current.ResetProgressRingState(false);
    }
```

I suspect that the `BindSearchResults` method needs to be awaited in order for the `ProgressRing` to work correctly. If so, what's the easiest way to make that method **awaitable**, if not please advise what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If so, what's the easiest way to make that method awaitable, if not please advise what I am missing here.

Mark it as `async` and have it return `Task`. Within that method, use `await` on other asynchronous operations.

Comment: This method contains a lot of UI interaction and no asynchronous calls in it. I can wrap it in await Task.Run, but in there I will have to wrap all the UI stuff in a dispatcher.RunAsync call. Seems like overkill to me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Added an await Task.Delay(10) in that method. Clean, simple, not sure if appropriate though.

Comment: I would not use `Task.Delay`. I assume that there is something in that method that is taking *time*, and that's why you want to show the progress indicator. You should look for what is taking up time; common culprits are disk or network I/O.

Comment: Given that it's a Metro app, I would expect I/O to be asynchronous. I suspect "a lot of UI interaction" to be the culprit.